# Why is my http://localhost:8080 not loading in node.js on mac

Tags: node.js

So I am very new to node.js and I am on a mac. I am learning from W3schools and I have to run myfirst.js in the local host but I keep getting this error:

This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

here is the code:

```
const https = require('https');
https.createServer(function (req,res){
   res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});
  res.send('Hello world!');
}).listen(8080);
```

and I ran this code in the terminal:

Macs-MBP:~ mac$ node /Users/mac/test/myfirst.js

the terminal command works but when i go to my browser and run :http://localhost:8080

I just keep getting the above error

how would I fix this?

Comment: You need to call `res.end()`. Either call `res.end()` after you've sent everything or replace `res.send()` with `res.end()` (just remove the "s")

Comment: (Welcome to stack**overflow**. There have been several versions of *Node.js*, more are likely: for prolonged usefulness of Q&A, please make it a habit to mention relevant versions used. To ask a [Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please add what documentation/resources you have already used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
const http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req,res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});
  res.write('<html><body><p>Hello world!</p></body></html>');
  res.end();
});
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Node.js web server running..')
```

Comment: Thank you all, this worked, also i had and s on http and was calling http, so it couldn't find it.

Comment: Also anyone has any good resources to learn node.js and react.